# Does SSL only encrypt form data, or the other part of the page as well?

Tags: networking

I have searched on google but the results didn't give me a definite answer.

Consider a situation, where you submit some confidential information in a form, then the server send you back some even more confidential information and your ajax call back update the page with that information. You definitely want both the form information and the information back to be securely encrypted.

Will SSL satisfy this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL encrypts all of the request headers and body, and all of the response headers and body.  As long as you submit your form to an `https` URL the content will be protected in both directions on the network.